# I can't access a new Web API controller that I've created in an existing project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In an existing ASP.NET MVC project, I've created a new Web API controller.

```cs
namespace EMSMVC.Controllers
{
    public class TabletController : ApiController
    {
        public Call Get(int call_id)
        {
            using(EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
            {
                return entities.Calls.FirstOrDefault(e => e.call_id == call_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to access it via browser using:

```
http://localhost:53366/Tablet/Call/157
```

I get the error:

> Server Error in '/'Application. The resource cannot be found.

My `RouteConfig.cs` contains:

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The `WebApiConfig.cs` file contains:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The existing controllers are working properly.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `http://localhost:53366/api/Tablet/Get/157`

Comment: @Rahul It does not work.

Comment: Can you please change the action signature as [HttpGet] public Call Get(int id) and access as http://localhost:53366/api/Tablet/157

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota I seems that is working. However now I get the error message `The 'ObjectContent\`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.` `Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.`

Comment: Its a serialization issue. Make sure both the serialization at "Call" model and "httpclient" in sync.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667918/objectcontent1-failed-to-serialize-the-response-from-dbset/61668157#61668157
Please add your comment as a response to accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change the action signature as [HttpGet] public Call Get(int id) and access as localhost:53366/api/Tablet/157

When you encounter any serialization issues then Make sure both the serialization at "Call" model and "httpclient" in sync.

Please find more details about ['ObjectContent`1': Failed to serialize the response from DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667918/)

Answer (score 1):

Try these two options:

Option 1. Use following URL:

```
http://localhost:53366/Tablet/Call?call_id=157
```

Option 2. Modify code like:

```
[RoutePrefix("tablet/services")]
public class TabletController : ApiController
{

    [Route("getcall")]
    [HttpGet, ActionName("getcall")]
    public Call Get(int call_id)
    {
        using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
        {
            return entities.Calls.FirstOrDefault(e => e.call_id == call_id);
        }
    }
}
```

and then try to call it with following URL:

```
http://localhost:53366/tablet/services/getcall/157
```

OR

```
http://localhost:53366/tablet/services/getcall?call_id=157
```

Comment: Thank you ATTA! The option `http://localhost:53366/tablet/services/getcall?call_id=157` is working. I'm using `[HttpGet, ActionName("getcall")]` instead of `[HttpPost, ActionName("getcall")]`.

Comment: Thanks @zinon, i updated the same in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, `{action}` is the method name, which in your controller is `Get`.  In your url (`http://localhost:53366/Tablet/Call/157`), you have `Call`, which is the return type of your method.  Try navigating to `http://localhost:53366/Tablet/Get/157`

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it with no luck.I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try http://localhost:53366/Tablet/Get/157

if still not work keep  add [HttpGet] like below

[HttpGet]
public Call Get(int call_id)

Comment: Stop IIS Explress once and then Please Try this one on Debug Mode http://localhost:53366/api/Tablet/Get/157,

Comment: I tried it and I got `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: Maybe the Call in the `Controller` is the issue? It refers to a class of Models.

Comment: [HttpGet]
public returntype methodnameOne (int _id)  
{
     return (“some Text”);     //Iam considering returntype  as "string"
}

Comment: OK, thanks! I need to return the fields of a database table.