# 'ObjectContent`1': Failed to serialize the response from DbSet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have the following controller in `TabletController.cs` file:

```cs
public class TabletController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable Get(int c_id)
    {
        using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
        {
            return entities.Calls.Where(e => e.call_id == c_id); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call:

```
http://localhost:53366/api/Tablet/157
```

But I get the following error:

> `Call` is`dDbSet`

Also, I need to get the results of the table's fields in `json` format. I tried to serialize it in JSON, but I get the same error.

```xml
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[EMSMVC.Models.Call, EMSMVC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfCall:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EMSMVC.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
```

My `WebApiConfig.cs` file is:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TabletCallApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{c_id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Tablet", action = "Get" }
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Also, my `RouteConfig.cs` is:

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding a `.ToList()` at the end of `entities.Calls.Where(e => e.call_id == c_id)` ... that works for you?

Comment: Change `public IQueryable Get(int c_id)` to `public List<Call> Get(int c_id)`. And change `return entities.Calls.Where(e => e.call_id == c_id);` to `return entities.Calls.Where(e => e.call_id == c_id).ToList();`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks, but I still get the same error.

Comment: could you write your Call class in your question?

Comment: @Marlonchosky I've just found the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing the response, so we could share the knowledge

Comment: @Marlonchosky Of course! I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I've changed the `TableController.cs` file to

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<Call> Get(int c_id)
    {
        using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
        {
            entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(entities.Calls.FirstOrDefault(e => e.call_id == c_id));
        }
    }
```